# Percentage Unit to Parent

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I'm sorry for this dumb question of mine but I thought the percentage unit is based to its parent element right?

then why here my button is overflowing to its div element?

Isnt the parent element of the button is the div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  button {
    padding: 50%;
  }
  

</style>

<div>
  <button> Touch This </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because two times 50%, plus the actual width of the button content, "Touch This", is _more_ than 100% ...?

Comment: don't forget to mark as resolved ;)

Comment: ohh yea yea I see I forgot that it actually includes the two sides thats why it doubled up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want you button to have exactly the size of its parent use :

```
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

the padding is not made to set the size of an element and as said by CBroe, two times 50% plus the size of the content is greater than 100% the size of the parent.

Comment: Almost accurate with logical changes!